# ANDROID - ListView ArrayAdapter (printing specific attribute)

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Im using listview in my listview activity with listAdapter like this:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<MyItem>(this,R.layout.catalog, R.id.label, items));
```

each item has item property ... how am i able to print it?

Comment: Can you show the getView code of your list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your listview layout add a `TextView`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/item_label"  />
</LinearLayout>
```

Set the value of this textview in your Custom Adapter override method getView

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.catalog, null);
        }
        MyItem m = items.get(position);
        TextView itemLabel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_label);
        itemLabel.setText(m.getItemLabel());        
        return v;
    }
```